# Exception при отправке писем вне домена // SMTP // C#

Tags: c#, исключения, smtp, sendmail

При отправке писем с помощью данного метода, письмо отправляются только на доменные п/я. При попытке отправить на иные (Google, Mail.ru) выдаёт Exception

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: "Удаленный сертификат недействителен согласно результатам проверки подлинности."

При подобных исключениях, советовали на callback сервера, передавать true (соглашаясь, что сертификат может быть не действительным).
  При использовании этого кода (закоменчены несколько вариантов), возвращается

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException: "Не удалось отправить всем получателям."
>
> SmtpFailedRecipientException: Почтовый ящик недоступен. Отклик сервера: 5.7.54 SMTP; Unable to relay recipient in non-accepted domain

Если этот де код использовать для отправки с mail.ru или google, исключений не возникает.

Просьба подсказать, где имеются ошибки или иные варианты решения.
Заранее спасибо.

```
<pre>
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Attachment = System.Net.Mail.Attachment;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace TestProg.DocSearchByParams.SystemMethods
{
    internal class MailSenderClass
    {
        private static void MailTo()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
            var fromMailAddress = new MailAddress("mail@from.ru", "test");
            var adr = new string[] {"mail11@mail.ru", "mail22@gmail.com" };

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var message = new MailMessage
                {
                    From = fromMailAddress
                };

                foreach (var P in adr)
                {
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(P));
                }

                message.Subject = "Тема + неделя: "
                                  + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) + " - "
                                  + DateTime.Now;
                message.Body = "Тело";
                var attach = @"F:\VS2017\Документ от " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".xlsx";
                //message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attach));

                smtp.Host = "mail.esphere.ru";
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Timeout = 30000;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromMailAddress.Address, "Password");


                /* Попытки избавиться от Exception "Сертификат не действителен" 
                 * ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                 * delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
                 * SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                 *  { return true; };
                */

                /*
                 * System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
                 *ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                 *    delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate,
                 *        X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                 *    { return true; };
                 */
                //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

                smtp.Send(message);

                message.Dispose();
                smtp.Dispose();
            }
        }
      </pre>
```

Comment: `Unable to relay...` обычно возникает, когда клиент не авторизовался на сервере, но при этом хочет отправить письмо на какой-либо другой почтовый домен (как правило через remote smtp). Вот вы уверены, что запись `NetworkCredential(fromMailAddress.Address, "Password");` на разных почтовиках будет одинаково воспринята? Я имею ввиду переменную `fromMailAddress.Address`. Возможно требуется вместо этого параметра указать `username`...

Comment: Пробовал передавать username в NetworkCredential, ошибка аналогичная 
SmtpFailedRecipientException: Почтовый ящик недоступен. Отклик сервера: 5.7.54 SMTP; Unable to relay recipient in non-accepted domain

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это возникает при попытке отправить через сервер `mail.esphere.ru`? Если да, то надо быть уверенным, что с этим юзернэймом/паролем/аккаунтом/etc на этом сервере все хорошо. Например, отправка писем не ограничена локалхостом или еще что-то. Что, если отправить письмо через этот сервер из обычного почтового клиента (aka Thunderbird), все ок?

Comment: Да, используется сервер mail.esphere.ru
Проверял на 2х аккаунтах, при отправке через почтовый клиент, проблем не возникает.

Answer (score 1):

@de_frag Спасибо, проблема решена, в

```
NetworkCredential(username, "Password")
```

передал domen/username как в почтовых клиентах